# Efficient way to index a Numpy array with another array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a Numpy array `x`, and an array of integers `y`, I want to do something equivalent to:

```
z = np.array(x[i] for i in y)
```

Is there a Numpy function/method to do this efficiently without converting back to a list?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `[x[i] for i in y]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `y` contains indices that are valid for `x`, then:

```
z = x[y]

>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(100)
>>> y = np.array([1, 27, 36, 98])
>>> x[y]
array([ 1, 27, 36, 98])
```

Comment: Ah of course - I was trying that but just realized that my y array had converted to float somewhere along the line.